# lxc 3.0.2 equivalent of lxc.network.type = veth

Tags: networking, 18.04, lxc

I have reinstalled from ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04.
My lxc container config had the following line:

```
lxc.network.type = veth
```

It no longer seems to work:

```
lxc-ls -l DEBUG  -f
lxc-ls: confile.c: set_config_net: 258 lxc.net must not have a value
lxc-ls: parse.c: lxc_file_for_each_line_mmap: 103 Failed to parse config: lxc.net = veth
Failed to load config for u1
```

Is there any equivalent for specify:
lxc.network.type, lxc.network.link, lxc.network.ipv4, lxc.network.ipv4.gateway and lxc.network.veth.pair ?

Answer (score 10):

Found a tip in /etc/lxc/default.conf:

```
lxc.network.type
```

as become

```
lxc.net.0.type
```

lxc.network.ipv4  -> lxc.net.0.ipv4.address

lxc.network.ipv4.gateway -> lxc.net.0.ipv4.gateway

lxc.network.veth.pair -> lxc.net.0.veth.pair

Also

lxc.rootfs and lxc.rootfs.backend  -> lxc.rootfs.path

Answer (score 6):

As of LXC 3.0 legacy config keys are not supported anymore.

For a reference on the deprecated keys and which ones replace them see this page:

https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/lxc-2-1-has-been-released/487

You can use `lxc-update-config` to update an old config to a new one.

My info comes from here:

https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/lxc-3-0-0-has-been-released/1449